# Should I Prime My (Painted Grey) Garage Walls Prior to Painting White?

Tags: painting, paint, priming

Painting grey walls white  - both paints are from the same base (Valspar 2000 Interior White/Pastel).

Will priming help before applying white paint, and if so, and how many coats of each (prime and/or paint) is recommended.

Comment: One my friends painted white over a dark colour without priming.  They needed many coats of paint to cover up the dark colour.  A very light grey you might get away with it.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the shade of gray, you're going to need a lot of cover.  That is one of primer's jobs - lay down a high-hiding effect that will render the surface uniform/consistent.  Since your topcoat is compatible, whether you use primer for coverage vs paint is a costing issue.

I would physically scuff-sand the old coating, especially if it's gloss. The goal is to give the surface some microscopic mountains, or "tooth", so the new paint has something to mold into, and you're not trying to paint a mirror. If you see peeling paint in rental properties, that's why - quickie paint jobs laid over gloss paint.

You also want to carefully clean the old surface with soap and water, preferably one made for paint prep that leaves no residue. That's the other reason rental property paint jobs tend to fail.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the grit used for scuffing the old coating?

Comment: @BabyDoll anything would do, 3M Scotbrite kitchen pads will suffice, 120-400 grit sandpaper, etc. It's not proper sanding, just scuffing. Try to avoid blowing through the old paint.